# How to compare and get matched fields in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have json data below

```
var dataA = {
   "state":"TX",
   "city":"Dallas",
   "code":"75201",
   "totalareas":"75201",
   "website":"asdf.ccom"      


}
```

and I have an array of objects

```
var dataB =[    
    {
     "key":"state",
     "value":"TX"

    },
    {
    "key":"city",
    "value":"Dallas"
    },
    {
     "key":"yu",
     "value":"2"
    },
   {
     "key":"website",
     "value":"asdf.ccom"
    }
    ]
```

I want to compare this dataA and dataB and get only matched fields with object how can I do this

My expectation result

```
{
   "city":"Dallas",
   "state":"TX",

}
```

Comment: What is your Question? the Output is inside the first JSON right?

Comment: There is no JSON in your question at all. Please read [What is the difference between JSON and Object Literal Notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2904131/what-is-the-difference-between-json-and-object-literal-notation)

Comment: I want to compare this dataA and dataB and get only matched fields

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to loop thru `dataB`. Convert each object into an array using `Object.entries` and use `forEach` to loop thru. If the key exist and the same value, assign the key and value to the accumulator.

```js
var dataA = {
  "state": "TX",
  "city": "Dallas",
  "code": "75201",
  "totalareas": "75201"
}

var dataB = [{
  "city": "Dallas",
  "citycode": "",
  "population": "234k"
}, {
  "state": "TX",
  "statecode": "asdf5678"
}, {
  "zip": "75201",
  "areacount": "567"
}]


var result = dataB.reduce((c, v) => {
  Object.entries(v).forEach(([i, o]) => {
    if (dataA[i] && dataA[i] === o) c[i] = o;
  })
  return c;
}, {});


console.log(result);
```

---

**UPDATE:** You dont need to convert each object into an array. You can use just use the key and value on the condition.

```js
var dataA = {"state":"TX","city":"Dallas","code":"75201","totalareas":"75201","website":"asdf.ccom"}
var dataB = [{"key":"state","value":"TX"},{"key":"city","value":"Dallas"},{"key":"yu","value":"2"},{"key":"website","value":"asdf.ccom"}]

var result = dataB.reduce((c, v) => {
  if (dataA[v.key] && dataA[v.key] === v.value) c[v.key] = v.value;
  return c;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: hai @Eddie can you pls help me out on this i have changed dataB object now i want to comapre

Comment: @realme you change it to?

Comment: hey sorry dataB look like this var dataA = {"state":"TX","city":"Dallas","code":"75201","totalareas":"75201","website":"asdf.ccom"}
var dataB = [{"key":"state","value":"TX"},{"key":"city","value":"Dallas"},{"key":"yu","value":"2"},{"key":"website","value":"asdf.ccom"}]

Comment: see now thay changed like this var dataB = [{"key":"state","value":"TX"},{"key":"city","value":"Dallas"},{"key":"yu","value":"2"},{"key":"website","value":"asdf.ccom"}]  but ur updated code is not working

Comment: Happy to help :)